# Rails: has_many: how to query for objects that have connections to some other objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a User model and a Authentication model. a `User` `has_many` `Authentications`.

I want to create a query that checks for all the users that have Authentication called 'Facebook' **AND** an Authentication called 'LinkedIn'.

I've tried joining twice, but this didn't work:

```
User.joins(:authentications).
where(authentications: {provider: 'facebook'}).
joins(:authentications).
where(authentications: {provider: 'linkedin'})
```

It resulted in the following query. It appears one of the joins is dropped:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "authentications"
ON "authentications"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE "authentications"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "authentications"."provider" = 'linkedin'
```

**edit:**

This worked for me, however, I had to join the user table twice, which I'd prefer not to do:

```
joins(authentications:{ user: :authentications }).where(authentications: {provider: 'facebook'}).where(authentications_users: {provider: 'linkedin'})
```

Comment: I think the SQL query did what you want. What do you means `one of the joins is dropped`? What results you got form this SQL quey?

Comment: I joined the authentications table twice, in order to find users who have two different authentications. The resulting query will never work since it only joins once. This won't work this way since the where clause looks for two different values in the save place.

Comment: Try this: `User.joins(:authentications).where("authentications.provider = ? AND authentications.provider = ?", 'facebook', 'linkedin' )`

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want. this query will never result in a right solution since the provider cannot be facebook and linkedin at the same time. I've found some other solution, see my edit.

Comment: You probably need an `OR` rathan than `AND`. Something like : `User.joins(:authentications).where("authentications.provider = ? OR authentications.provider = ?", 'facebook', 'linkedin' )`

Comment: I don't think so. This will just get back all of the rows of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can indeed join the same table twice. I'm not sure how AR will handle two `.joins` calls with symbol arguments, but you can surely do something like that:

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN authentications AS a1 ON a1.user_id = users.id").
     joins("INNER JOIN authentications AS a2 ON a2.user_id = users.id").
     where("a1.provider = 'linkedin'").where("a2.provider = 'facebook'")
```

It ends up in crafting lower level SQL, but this way you will be able to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks. This one did the trick: User.joins("INNER JOIN authentications AS a1 ON a1.user_id = users.id").joins("INNER JOIN authentications AS a2 ON a2.user_id = users.id").where("a1.provider = 'linkedin'").where("a2.provider = 'facebook'")

Comment: I still wonder if there's a way to do that without using the lower level SQL